# Arc enabled Cocos2d: Schedule Crash

Tags: timer, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, schedule

I recently managed to enable ARC on my project, by following this tutorial

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/

Everything worked until i added a schedule method like:

```
[self schedule:@selector(test:) interval:0.1];
```

Method:

```
-(void)test:(id)timer{
    NSLog(@"yes!");
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesnt say 'yes!', instead it crashes with:

```
0x1de8d83:  movl   (%eax), %edx
```

And shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it would be ok to just use:

```
-(void)test:(id)timer;
```

Instead use:

```
-(void)test:(ccTime)dt;
```

Didn't have this problem when ARC wasn't enabled yet.

Comment: It wouldn't have worked before (accessing timer would have crashed). It may simply not have crashed because you didn't access timer, but it certainly wasn't correct. With ARC, the id parameter's memory became managed by ARC, but since it's a float and not an id when ARC either tries to retain or release it, it'll crash.